# Javascript TypeError event exception on Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I'm trying to add a FileReader onload event for Chrome, it works fine on Firefox but throws a TypeError exception when I try on Chrome.

Here's my code:

```
function random(min, max)
{
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}

function handleDrop(event) {
    var dt = event.dataTransfer,
        files = dt.files,
        count = files.length;

    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();

    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        var fileReader = new FileReader();

        fileReader.addEventListener("loadend", function(e) {
            xn = random(0, $('canvas').attr('width'));
            yn = random(0, $('canvas').attr('height'));
            widthn = random(100, 200);

            $("canvas").drawImage({
                source: e.target.result,
                fromCenter: false,
                x: xn,
                y: yn,
                width: widthn
            });

            delete e.target.result;
        } , false);

        fileReader.readAsDataURL(files[i]);
    }
}

$(document).ready(function()
{
    var dropContainer = document.getElementById("content");

    dropContainer.addEventListener("dragenter", function(event){event.stopPropagation();event.preventDefault();}, false);
    dropContainer.addEventListener("dragover", function(event){event.stopPropagation();event.preventDefault();}, false);
    dropContainer.addEventListener("drop", handleDrop, false);

});
```

I'm using the Chrome script debugger and the exception is throwing at the following line:

```
fileReader.addEventListener("loadend", function(e) {
```

What can I do to fix this in Chrome?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well obviously, `FileReader` doesn't have `addEventListener`. (`TypeError: Object #<FileReader> has no method 'addEventListener'`)

Use:

```
var fileReader = new FileReader();

fileReader.onloadend = function (e) {
    xn = random(0, $('canvas').attr('width'));
    yn = random(0, $('canvas').attr('height'));
    widthn = random(100, 200);

    $("canvas").drawImage({
        source: e.target.result,
        fromCenter: false,
        x: xn,
        y: yn,
        width: widthn
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You should probably make sure you're explicitly converting the CSS properties to numbers before sending them to that "random()" function.

```
        // ...
        xn = random(0, ~~$('canvas').attr('width'));
        yn = random(0, ~~$('canvas').attr('height'));
```

You could use `parseInt()` of course; that's just an example; so alternatively:

```
        // ...
        xn = random(0, parseInt($('canvas').attr('width'), 10));
        yn = random(0, parseInt($('canvas').attr('height'), 10));
```

Also of course the variables should be declared with `var`:

```
        // ...
        var xn = random(0, ~~$('canvas').attr('width'));
        var yn = random(0, ~~$('canvas').attr('height'));
```

Comment: This will only make the random function work properly :P ( I get very different results for `random( 5, 10 )` and `random( "5", "10" )` ) but it doesn't cause TypeError

Comment: Hmm ... well I don't know then.